# pip3 list コマンド実行時に外部への通信が発生するのを抑制したい

Tags: python, pip

"pip3 list"コマンドに関しての質問になります。

#### 課題

Linuxサーバ上で `pip3 list` を実行してパッケージ情報の収集をする際、外部（146.75.112.223）への通信が発生します。
対象のLinuxサーバはファイヤーウォールにより外部への通信を制限しており、`pip3 list` の実行の度にアラートが発生している状況です。
ちなみに、`pip list` の実行ではこの問題は発生しませんでした。

#### 解決したいこと

`pip3 list` の実行のたびにアラートが発生するという状況を阻止したく、`pip3 list` の実行の際に外部への通信が発生しないようにすることはできますでしょうか。
また、外部への通信が発生する理由もわかるととてもありがたいです。

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `-l`のオプションを付けてみる。`--no-index --find-links=<local_folder>`のオプションを付けてみる。(`<local_folder>`は有効なフォルダパスを指定) [pip list](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_list/), [Install Python Packages via Pip without an Internet Connection](https://thilinamad.medium.com/install-python-packages-via-pip-without-an-internet-connection-b3dee83b4c2d) あるいは `list` の代わりに `freeze` を使う。とかを試してみてはどうでしょう？ [Python, pip list / freezeでインストール済みパッケージ一覧を確認](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pip-list-freeze/)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。参考にさせていただきます

Comment: @katsuko さんの答えのほうが合ってそうな感じなので、おそらくこちらの記事が参考になるでしょう。[How to suppress pip upgrade warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46288847/9014308)

Answer (score 0):

listコマンドに限った話ではないですが、pipを実行すると

```
[notice] A new release of pip is available:
```

というメッセージが出ることがあるではないですか。
これってつまり、**どこかのサーバにpipの最新バージョンを問い合わせている**ということじゃないですか。

pipのヘルプを見たところ、`--disable-pip-version-check` というオプションでこの処理を抑制できるようなので、試してみてはいかがですか。(もしくは、コメントにある通り `--no-index` でも可)

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます、参考にさせていただきます。